# Compare Char in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, char

For some HomeWork, I need to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game. 
I make the game with no problems, but now I need to control if a player as win. For that purpose, I need to compare some Char present in an array. 
So I set up a test with an "if", but it sends me an error (CS0019 in Visual Studio) that says I cannot compare char and expect a bool output. 
How do I circumvent that?

```
if ((casesMorpion[0, 0]) != (casesMorpion[1, 0]) != (casesMorpion[2, 0]))
{
  V1 = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `(casesMorpion[0, 0]) != (casesMorpion[1, 0]) != (casesMorpion[2, 0])` on a single line and expect it to work.

You get your error because `(casesMorpion[0, 0]) != (casesMorpion[1, 0])` is a `bool`, and you try to compare it to `(casesMorpion[2, 0])` which is a `char`.

You should split it into two conditions with a logical and `&&`:

```cs
if (casesMorpion[0, 0] != casesMorpion[1, 0] && casesMorpion[1, 0] != (casesMorpion[2, 0]))
{
    V1 = true;
}
```

Or anything else, since I don't know exactly what you are trying to test.

Comment: This is programmatically fine. And its just that I think both the comparison operations have to be combined with OR and not AND

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Corentin Pane answer. He answered just few seconds before me

Some thing like below could help

```
var expectedChar = casesMorpion[0, 0]; 
if ((expectedChar != casesMorpion[1, 0]) || (expectedChar != casesMorpion[2, 0]))
{
    V1 = true;
}
```

!= operation between two operands give a bool. so now it will become bool != char this will give a compilation error.